# Lightweight android launcher

Tags: gratis, android, launcher

I'm currently looking for a launcher with the smallest footprint as possible.

- whether it looks like stock or not doesn't matter
- it shouldn't have a "Prime" version that is to say no paid features
- supports icon packs
- widgets integration is a must
- customizable
- **lightweight** enough with a tiny footprint for a cheap smartphone

Comment: @Izzy thank you I will take a look at zeam launcher. Your link requiores a login though

Comment: Sorry for that: wrong URL causes this. As I cannot edit that comment anymore, delete there and re-write here (with working URL): The "no prime" part makes it a little hard for me to put an answer. I've settled with Apex, but you might wish to take a look at my list of [Home Replacements](http://android.izzysoft.de/applists.php?topic=cat;id=179). *Zeam Launcher* was a pretty good choice back with my *HTC Wildfire* (aka "Buzz"), but I'm not sure how it continued/evolved.

Comment: @Izzy thank you that makes a lot!!! I'll take a look. Zeam launcher is discontinued, however, I am testing another launche rby the same author, SickSky Launcher.

Comment: Discontinued? Last update 2014-06-30 doesn't sound like that (but "no longer under development" does, sadly, it was very handsome). Also worth a look: Solo Launcher. I've read best of Nova and Apex, but completely free. Had no time to check it out myself, but it's on my list...

Comment: That is what I am actually using. Awesome but takes too much memory